# how can I write a regression model in matrix form?

Tags: matrices, statistics

The question is

$$y_{ij} = \mu + \nu d_{2j} + \beta x'_{ij} +\varepsilon_{ij} \text{ where }i= 1 ,\ldots, n,\  j= 1,2$$

So I am trying to write this model in  matrix form.

I know how to put $d_{2j}$, $\varepsilon_{ij}$, and $x'_{ij}$ in matrix form.

$d_{2j} = 2\times1$ matrix

$\varepsilon_{ij} = n\times 2$ matrix

$x'_{ij} = 2\times1$ matrix.

am I correct??

and also i am not sure what to do with $μ$ and $ν$. are these just constant??

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} y_{1,1} \\  \vdots \\ y_{n,1} \\ y_{2,1} \\  \vdots \\ y_{2,n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} d_{2,1} \\  \vdots \\ d_{2,1} \\ d_{2,2} \\ \vdots \\ d_{2,2} \end{bmatrix}\nu + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_{1,1} \\  \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{1,n} \\ 1 & x_{2,1} \\  \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{2,n}  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{1,1} \\
\vdots \\ \varepsilon_{n,1} \\  \varepsilon_{1,2} \\ \vdots \\ \varepsilon_{n,2} \end{bmatrix}
$$

That's one way.

I thought of using an $n\times 2$ matrix for $y$ and $n\times 3$ for $x$, but that would have required a column with $\mu$ and two separate copies of $\beta$.  Somehow it seemed better to let each of the three parameters to be estimated appear only once.